# Random DOUBLE PRECISION between

Tags: postgresql

How can I get a random number between two `DOUBLE PRECISION` number?

The following generate number outside of range

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_between(low DOUBLE PRECISION, high DOUBLE PRECISION)
    RETURNS DOUBLE PRECISION AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN random() * (high - low + 1) + low;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql' STRICT;
```

Comment: Note that a `language sql` function would be faster.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please tell me why `language sql` is faster? is there any official resource?

Comment: Because it has less overhead that PL/pgSQL (no context switch)

Comment: Do you have any resources, I am willing to read more

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=08f4cb0cdb58bf8a15220a86dba4f560

Comment: WOW!! It's awesome, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=67c3c23762961606db72f75025f680f1)

Remove the `+ 1` from the range.